# Run multiple web apps on the same ip

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Let's assume I have Apache HTTP Server, an ip address and I don't any domain names. My question is how to run two web apps on the same ip but different ports. 
 For example:

- App_1 runs on ip_address:port_1
- App_2 runs on ip_address:port_2

So I can access both of by typing ip address and port number in address line of browser. As I understand it's called IP-based virtual hosts.

Comment: That is correct and it will work. I suggest you simply take a look at the documentation for virtual hosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/ip-based.html

Comment: However you might also want to consider getting a registered domain. It comes for a few Euros a year and allows you to use multiple hostnames under that domain name (sometimes called "subdomains"). So something like `app1.example.com`. That is easier to use than the technical notation of ip addresses and port numbers and simplifies the firewall configuration, since you can operate all apps on a single port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the httpd.conf filr in Apache/conf you have to create VirtualHosts like below:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost IPAddress:80>
    ServerName localhost:80
    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/var/www/GP/GP/wsgi.py"
    Alias /static/ "C:/var/www/GP/static/"
    Alias /templates/ "C:/var/www/GP/templates/"
    <Directory "C:/var/www/GP/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/var/www/GP/GP">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost IPAddress:81>
    ServerName localhost:81
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/adminSVNProject/adminSVNProject/wsgi.py
    Alias /static/ /var/www/adminSVNProject/static/
    Alias /templates/ /var/www/adminSVNProject/templates/
    <Directory /var/www/adminSVNProject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/adminSVNProject/adminSVNProject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/GP;/var/www/adminSVNProject;
```

If your files are in C:var/www
Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Same setup for me.  For me, I put nginx as a reverse proxy in front of 2 separate apache servers.  Each running a python/django application.

I set up each apache server to listen on a different port and then directed nginx to send to the correct application server based on location.  One application at root (doesn't have to be) and one at /application2.   This worked fine, however periodically, application 2 users would be redirected to the root application.  Took me some time to track down what was causing it.  Simple problem with simple fix:   404 on Favicon.ico on application 2.  The server would sometimes look at the root or "default" location for the file and the next click, users would redirect to the root folder application.   As long as your favicon.ico is there and defined in base.html, it works fine without redirect.